# Combine result of promises into a single array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback, promise, es6-promise

I try to parse all the files that were uploaded as a directory upload into a single array of files. I have a problem that I cannot combine result of all the promises into a single array. I get a multidimensional array instead.

```
function iterateThroughUploadedFiles(files, isEntry = false) {
    var promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let entry = isEntry ? files[i].webkitGetAsEntry() : files[i];
        if (entry.isFile) {
            promises.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                getFile(entry, resolve, reject);
            }));
        }
        else if (entry.isDirectory) {
            let dirReader = entry.createReader();

            var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                readEntries(dirReader, resolve, reject);
            });

            promises = promises.concat(promise);
        }
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

function getFile(fileEntry, resolve, reject) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        resolve(file)
    });
}

function readEntries(dirReader, resolve, reject) {
    dirReader.readEntries(function (entries) {
        resolve(iterateThroughEntries(entries).then(function(result) {
            return result;
        }));
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
iterateThroughUploadedFiles(files, true).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

When I execute `iterateThroughUploadedFiles` function the `result` variable is a multidimensional array. However, I want this array to be flattened (example: *[File(6148), Array(1), Array(0), File(14)]*). I am not very familiar with callbacks and Promises...therefore, I have some issues working with them.

**Edit:** 
There is a typo I made inside `readEntries(dirReader, resolve, reject)` function. There should be `iterateThroughUploadedFiles` instead of `iterateThroughEntries` function.

Comment: `readEntries` and  `getFile` should *return* a promise that they construct themselves, not take `resolve`/`reject` as callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return Promise.all(promises);
```

That resolves to a two dimensional array, which you can easily flatten by using some generator functions:

```
function* flatten(arr) {
  for(const el of arr) {
    if(Array.isArray(el)) {
      yield* flatten(el);
    } else {
      yield el;
    }
  }
}

return Promise.all(promises).then(array => ([...flatten(array)]));
```

---

While passing `resolve` and `reject` works kind of, that can be done way more elegant with just returning a new Promise from the `getFile` function:

```
function getFile(fileEntry, resolve, reject) {
   return new Promise(resolve => fileEntry.file(resolve));
}
```

Then it can be easily chained

```
function readEntries(dirReader) {
  return new Promise(resolve => dirReader.readEntries(resolve))
    .then(iterateThroughEntries);
}

function iterateThroughUploadedFiles(files, isEntry = false) {
   return Promise.all( files.map( file => {
     let entry = isEntry ? file.webkitGetAsEntry() : file;
     if (entry.isFile) {
       return getFile(entry);
     } else if (entry.isDirectory) {
       return readEntries( entry.createReader());
     }
   })).then(array => ([...flatten(array)]));
}
```

Comment: I would've thought `array => [].concat(...array)` would be how to flatten a two dimensional array - or even `[].concat.apply([], array)` if the JS engine in question supports arrow functions but not spread operator

Comment: This solves only two dimensional problem but is it possible that I have more dimensional arrays.

Comment: @david, yes it is, have a look at the edited version ;)

Comment: It's possible to use [Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) instead of `flatten`